# undefined subroutine &main:: called at Any.pm Issue with Thread::Queue::Any

Tags: multithreading, perl

Am trying to use the Any.pm module ,i have downloaded the module and with below code,am facing the error

"undefined subroutine &main::  called at Any.pm line 52"

Code:

```
use lib "/threads-module/Thread-Queue-Any-1.14/lib/";
require "/threads-module/Thread-Queue-Any-1.14/lib/Thread/Queue/Any.pm";
our $wt_to_mt_queue = Thread::Queue::Any->new();

$wt_to_mt_queue->enqueue($reference);
```

Not sure what is missing ??

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing a `require`, instead of `use Thread::Queue::Any;` ?  Also, the method is `enqueue`, not `en queue`.  Is that space a random copy&paste artifact?

Comment: I tried with "use" as well,am facing the same problem.Its a typing error,am using enqueue in my code

Comment: `our`?!?!?! You should never have a use for `our`! Use `my`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I attempted to recreate this error by first installing [`Thread::Queue::Any`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Thread%3a%3aQueue%3a%3aAny) by using `cpan Thread::Queue::Any`, and then running the following script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Thread::Queue::Any;

my $reference;
our $wt_to_mt_queue = Thread::Queue::Any->new();
$wt_to_mt_queue->enqueue($reference);
```

**This finished with no warnings or errors**

I then looked into the [`source of Thread::Queue::Any`](https://metacpan.org/source/ELIZABETH/Thread-Queue-Any-1.14/lib/Thread/Queue/Any.pm) and lines 50-52 are the following:

```
sub enqueue {
    return shift->SUPER::enqueue( $FREEZE->( \@_ ) );
} #enqueue
```

The only subroutine that is called here is `$FREEZE` which looking closer at the source, is initialized by the `import` method at line 151 (we can see where this is going now).

So I then decided to duplicate your use of `require`, but first I had to figure out where my `Thread::Queue::Any` is hiding:

```
use Thread::Queue::Any;
use Data::Dump;

dd \%INC;
```

Apparently it's in `"Thread/Queue/Any.pm"  => "C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Thread/Queue/Any.pm",`.  So to mirror your use of `require`, I do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#use Thread::Queue::Any;
require 'C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/thread/Queue/Any.pm';

my $reference;
our $wt_to_mt_queue = Thread::Queue::Any->new();
$wt_to_mt_queue->enqueue($reference);
```

And this gives me the following output:

```
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/thread/Queue/Any.pm line 51.
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/thread/Queue/Any.pm line 51.
Can't use string ("") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/thread/Queue/Any.pm
line 51.
```

Now this doesn't completely mirror your error, but I still conclude that you're not using the module right by not actually [`using`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) the module.

Also given where the module is stored on your system, I suspect you aren't actually installing the it which you should using cpan or one of the equivalents.

Comment: It helped me to resolve atleast this error but now i see a completely new error.                                              The error in enqueue is Can't store CODE items at blib/lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into blib/lib/auto/Storable/_freeze.al) line 339, at /home/threadsmodule/Thread-Queue-Any-1.14/lib//Thread/Queue/Any.pm line 54

Comment: I tried the following: `my $ref = sub { print "hello "; }; $wt_to_mt_queue->enqueue($ref);` and got the same error.  However, this module doesn't appear intended to store code references, only data structures.  Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you bother setting up lib if you pass the full path to require? The following is better than what you have:

```
use lib "/threads-module/Thread-Queue-Any-1.14/lib";
require "Thread/Queue/Any.pm";
```

Better yet:

```
use lib "/threads-module/Thread-Queue-Any-1.14/lib";
require Thread::Queue::Any;
```

But why are you using `require`???

```
use lib "/threads-module/Thread-Queue-Any-1.14/lib";
use Thread::Queue::Any qw( );
```

The `qw( )` means you don't want to import anything from the module. Unfortunately, Thread::Queue::Any has crucial logic in the `import` sub -- that's a bad design -- so one has to use he following:

```
use lib "/threads-module/Thread-Queue-Any-1.14/lib";
use Thread::Queue::Any;
```

This imports the default exports -- of which there are none -- but it also ends up calling the misplaced code in T::Q::A.